# Coded UI: Can we perform drag & drop without consuming mouse?

Tags: automation, automated-tests, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

I have used Selenium Web driver in the past and because it utilizes the browser driver, it can perform things like drag and drop without actually moving the mouse. The problem with performing drag and drop with mouse is that you can't actually open anything else or move your mouse while you are running your tests. I am wondering if Coded UI has similar feature?

Kindly take into consideration that I do not want to use the test recorder, instead I am using the more flexible approach and building UI test through the Page Model. That means I am hand coding all my tests.

Comment: You cannot. All CUI tests "steal" the mouse. Period.

Answer (score 0):

Afraid not. It will always use the mouse to do the interaction.

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("source"));
      WebElement target = driver.findElement(By.name("target"));

     (new Actions(driver)).dragAndDrop(element, target).perform();
```